# Binary number 11 represents?

Tags: digital-logic

I was going through some of the questions in my textbook and I got stucked up here. Kindly help me with this

The Binary number 11 represents **__**

```
   1) -3 in sign magnitude and -1 in 2's complement
   2) 7 in sign magnitude and -1 in 2's complement
   3) -3 in sign magnitude and -3 in 2's complement
   4) 7 in sign magnitude and -3 in 2's complement
```

The answer was 'c'. But I am unable to figure out the reason why and I cant even trust it because I am unable to judge the answer. Please help me with these. Thanks

Comment: If the choices are answers 1-4, selecting answer C is not a good way to score points on a test.

Comment: Title, author, ISBN number, chapter and section, or else it doesn't exist and you're trolling.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can answer this question, you have to understand the various binary encodings being talked about.  The two in question are *2s complement* and *sign-magnitude*

**Sign-Magnitude**

Zero and positive numbers are represented as you would probably expect.  Let's say we have 4 bit binary.  0000 is zero, 0001 is one, 0010 is two, etc.  Each digit position is worth the number base times the one on its right.  The right most is worth one.  Therefore, in binary, the digit positions from right to left are worth 1, 2, 4, and 8.  To decode a number, you multiply each digit by the worth of its bit position, and add up the results.  For example, 1010 would be 1x8 + 0x4 + 1x2 + 0x1 = ten.  This is exactly how numbers are written in other bases, including decimal.  The decimal number 1234 has the value 1x1000 + 2x100 + 3x10 + 4x1.

The problem is how to represent negative numbers.  When writing in decimal, we put a negative sign in front of the number.  That's pretty much what sign-magnitude binary representation does too.  Usually the high bit is reserved as the "sign" bit, with 0 indicating zero or positive and 1 indicating negative.  The rest of the bits have the same meaning as before.

For example, using 4 bit numbers again, 0101 is five (1x4 + 0x2 + 1x1).  To make negative 5, we simply set the sign bit resulting in 1101.  So in 4 bit sign-magnitude format, the binary number 1101 has the value minus five.

**2s Complement**

The above works fine and is a lot like what we do ourselves with decimal, but it's not so convenient to implement with logic gates in a computer.  Nowadays, 2s complement is pretty much universal inside computers.  Zero and positive numbers are represented as before.  The difference is how negative numbers are represented.

One advantage of 2s complement is that nothing special needs to be done to add negative versus positive numbers.  Think about what bit pattern would result in 0000 after you add 1 to it.  If the addition rule is followed, then whatever that number is must be -1.  Hopefully you know how to add binary numbers, and can see that 1111 + 0001 results in 0000.  Actually it results in 10000, but since we are only dealing with 4 bit numbers, the fifth bit that results from the add is lost and we are left with the low 4 bits 0000.  There are only 16 possible values a 4 bit binary number can represent, and if using the 2s complement scheme they are:

```
Binary  Decimal
  0111        7
  0110        6
  0101        5
  0100        4
  0011        3
  0010        2
  0001        1
  0000        0
  1111       -1
  1110       -2
  1101       -3
  1100       -4
  1011       -5
  1010       -6
  1001       -7
  1000       -8
```

So maybe you can see that the question you asked is ambiguous.  It is important to know the width of the binary number being used.  For example, if the question is assuming 4 bits numbers as my example above, then 11 (assumed to be 0011 with the leading zeros not shown) is three.  The same is true for a bit width of 3 or more.  If it is only 2 bits, then there are only 4 possible values such a number can express.

This is your homework, so I'm not just going to give you the answer.  A good way to proceed would be to make a table of all possible 2 bit binary numbers and their decimal equivalents as I did above, but for both 2s complement and sign-magnitude.  If you show at least a reasonable attempt, we can discuss it further.

Answer (score 2):

A two bit signed number cannot represent -3 in two's complement or in sign-magnitude.

```
bits     two's complement value    sign-magnitude value
00        0                         0
01        1                         1
10       -2                         0
11       -1                        -1
```

Two's complement has an extra negative value (which has no additive inverse). Sign magnitude has two zeros.

Now let's look at your question.

No nonzero bit pattern can have negative value in one representation and a positive value in the other. In both representations, the high bit functions as a negative sign. Therefore, answers 2 and 4 cannot be correct answers for any bit pattern.

Furthermore, no bit pattern can have the same negative value in both representations. A bit pattern cannot be -3 in two's complement and -3 in one's complement. So answer 3 is also impossible. (Proof: two's complement -3, in any width, ends in 01: 101, 1101, 11101, ... but a sign-magnitude -3 must end in 11:  111, 1011, 10011, ...)

The only possible correct answer for *some* bit pattern is 1:

```
1) -3 in sign magnitude and -1 in 2's complement
```

However, it is not the correct answer for the given bit pattern `11`. The situation described in 1 is possible, and it fits the bit pattern `1111` under four bit arithmetic. This number is -3 in four bit sign magnitude, and -1 in four bit two's complement.

The question must have a typo, or you copied it down wrong.

If a solution guide you are looking at gives C as the solution for a multiple choice question whose answers are numerically denoted, you are probably looking at the incorrect solution guide. Wrong section, wrong chapter, wrong textbook. This seems like an unlikely mistake.
M

Comment: If you use the (somewhat uncommon) sign bit 0=negative 1=positive then 0b1111 would be 7 in sign-magnitude and -1 in 2s-complement, so answer 0b1010 (or 0b0010) would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sign magnitude uses the most significant bit to denote the sign.  0 is usually positive, 1 negative.  With a 2-bit number like 0b11, the sign bit makes it negative with only 2 possible values for the magnitude:  0 and 1.  In this case, it would be -1.

But this is not an option.  I really think they meant to ask **The binary number 0b111 represents *_***.  This would make more sense, as 0b111 would be negative, with a magnitude of 3 for sign magnitude form.  Or -3, which is one of the options.

Two's complement is a bit more complicated, but not much.  Two's complement uses the highest order bit to denote negativity as well.  The magnitude of a negative number is found by complementing the number (0b111 becomes 0b000, 0b101 would become 0b010) and adding 1.  This sounds silly, but it makes addition of signed numbers very simple, no extra logic is required.  The magnitude of a positive number (with the most significant bit 0) is simply the number.

So the number is (I'm assuming) 0b111, so it's negative.  Complement it and add one yields 0b000, then 0b001, so it's negative and its magnitude is 1, so it's -1.

So..  unless I'm completely wrong, and I might be considering I haven't done this by hand for a while, the answer is (1), not (3) (or C?) as you suggested.  But since the question as you typed it was obviously wrong, the whole thing just might be wrong.

I just have to ask which textbook this is.

Comment: You are mixing the concept of binary numbers with the very specific way they are represented in the C computer language.  If you are going to use a specific language convention that has nothing to do with the question, you should at least state that clearly.

Comment: UM is just using the prefix 0b to denote a binary number. AFAIK this is not valid C (alhtough it is accepted by some compilers).

Comment: @Wouter: I though it came from C, but the point is that it is specific to a particular computer language, not general mathematics, which this question is about.  For example, in Apollo Domain Pascal you would write 2#101 for the value 5 in binary, but I wouldn't use that to answer a question either unless it was about that language or I defined the convention I was using.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant.  I'm just in the habit of putting _something_ there to denote the base, it wasn't from any language in particular.