# Why are 11, 111, 1111, ... equivalent to -1 in two's complement?

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, vlsi, alu

According to [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), the binary numbers 111 and 11111111 are equivalent to -1. Why or how are the binary numbers 11, 111, 1111, 1111 1111, etc. equivalent to -1 in two's complement? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Note that in 2's complement, 011 and 11 are different numbers.

Comment: This has been discussed various times before. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/32279/4512, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/163818/4512.

Answer (score 8):

In an unsigned binary representation, only positive numbers can be represented,  and the weight of each bit including the most significant bit is a power of two.

So with a word size of 8 (byte),

```
00000000 => 0
01111111 => 127
10000000 => 128
11111111 => 255
```

Two's-complement, which is used for signed binary notation, encodes both positive and negative numbers in a binary number representation. The weight of each bit is a power of two, *except for the most significant bit*, whose weight is the negative of the corresponding power of two.

```
00000000 => 0
01111111 => 127
10000000 => -128    (in unsigned notation, this bit was 128, now its -128)
11111111 => -1
```

For a given word size N, all 1's in two's complement will represent -1.  So if the word size is only two bits, 11 is -1.  But if the word size is 8 bits (a byte), then 11 is simply 3 and 11111111 is -1.

The is because the two's complement of an n-bit number is defined as the complement with respect to 2\$^{N}\$; i.e., it is the result of subtracting the number from 2\$^{N}\$, which in binary is one followed by N zeroes.

So if N = 2 (first example), so 2\$^{2}\$=4,

```
 100
  -1
 011
```

truncating to two bits gives 11.  (**-2** + 1 = -1)

For N = 8 (first example), so 2\$^{8}\$=256,

```
 100000000
        -1
 011111111
```

truncating to eight bits gives 11111111.   (**-128** + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = -1)

Answer (score 6):

In 2's complement the MSb is defined as -(2<sup>n</sup>) where n is the bit position of the MSb. Due to how numbers work, all bits other than the MSb add up to (2<sup>n</sup>)-1. Adding those together results in -1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non mathematical explanation, just intuitive one.

Ask yourself how many times you'll need to add 1 until you get to 0.

In all of your examples the answer for that question is 1. 
And because that's also true for -1 these numbers equal to -1.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see this (which can be seen as expanding on both of the previous answers, or ripping off [my own answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1193944/138178)) is this: for every n, the n-bit unsigned integers (n-bit words representing an interval of the natural numbers starting at 0) form a cyclic structure with 2<sup>n</sup> members—because of overflow, the successor of 111...1 (which represents 2<sup>n</sup>-1) is 000...0 (which represents 0); so instead of being arranged in a line as the naturals, the n-bit words are arranged in a circle. This structure is known as the cyclic group Z<sub>2<sup>n</sup></sub>.

Now the question is: how can we use *the same* cyclic structure to represent an interval of the integers containing negative numbers as well as positive ones? One possible answer would be to "shift" the whole thing to the left—000...0 would represent the smallest number in the interval, namely -2<sup>n</sup>, and 111...1 would represent the largest, namely 2<sup>n</sup>-1; 0 would be represented by 100...0 somewhere in the middle. That actually could work, but implementing the arithmetic logic would get very ugly. :)

Instead, we take advantage of the cyclic structure. We leave the words 000...0 to 011...1 representing the non-negative side of our interval, namely 0 to 2<sup>n</sup>-1, and "move" the words 100...0 to 111...1 to the negative side, representing -2<sup>n</sup> to -1. This works out nicely: the successor of 111...1 is indeed 000...0 (in other words, -1+1=0). We can now leave all of the addition logic unchanged from unsigned arithmetic, and other operations are also easy to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of question has been answered before, but it looks like this particular wording of the question is turning up in a lot of search results, so I'll repost my answer from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163818/why-all-1s-used-as-a-second-input-in-decrement-operation-of-alu).

It might be easier to understand this in decimal. Imagine that we're doing arithmetic on three-digit base 10 numbers: 445, 900, 132, 042, 007, etc. We can add the numbers together, but the result is always truncated to three digits. Here's an example:

> \$900 + 132 =  1032 \to 032\$

Now, look what happens when we add 999 to a number:

> \$042 + 999 = 1041 \to 041\$
>
> \$041 + 999 = 1040 \to 040\$
>
> \$040 + 999 = 1039 \to 039\$

As long as we drop the fourth digit, adding 999 (the largest possible three-digit number) works just like subtracting 1!

Binary works the same way. With four-bit numbers, adding the largest possible four-bit number works just like subtracting 1. Again, this is because we're dropping the carry out from the high bit.

> \$0110 + 1111 = 10101 \to 0101\$
>
> \$0101 + 1111 = 10100 \to 0100\$
>
> \$0100 + 1111 = 10011 \to 0011\$
>
> \$0011 + 1111 = 10010 \to 0010\$

This is called *two's complement arithmetic*. Using this system, you can compute the "negative" of any n-bit binary number by subtracting it from \$2^n\$. For four-bit numbers, it works like this:

> \$-1 = 2^4 - 1 = 10000 - 0001 = 1111\$
>
> \$-5 = 2^4 - 5 = 10000 - 0101 = 1011\$

So adding 1011 to a four-bit number is just like subtracting 5, as long as you drop the last carry.

There's a faster and more common way to compute the two's complement -- invert all of the bits, then add one. This lets you compute a four-bit negative using inversion and addition, instead of needing five-bit subtraction. Here's how to compute -1 and -5 using this method:

> \$-1 = \lnot 0001 + 1 = 1110 + 1 = 1111\$
>
> \$-5 = \lnot 0101 + 1 = 1010 + 1 = 1011\$

Answer (score 0):

Several answers are alluding to [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) without actually discussing it. I believe this is a valuable perspective and makes two's complement a lot easier to grasp.

Both unsigned and two's complement arithmetic on *n*-bit numbers can be naturally considered as **operations modulo 2<sup>n</sup>**.

#### Modular Arithmetic

For those not familiar with modular arithmetic, it is a system of numbers where adding or subtracting \$m\$ does not change the value of a number. This means the system is "circular" and once you go through \$m\$ steps you end up back where you started.

Let's take an example. If we are working with 2-bit numbers, we take \$m=2^2 = 4\$. We say we are working "modulo 4". In this system, adding or subtracting 4 does not change a number's value.

This means 5 = 1, 6 = 2, and so on. In fact we have:

```
... = -8 = -4 = 0 = 4 =  8 = 12 = ...
... = -7 = -3 = 1 = 5 =  9 = 13 = ...
... = -6 = -2 = 2 = 6 = 10 = 14 = ...
... = -5 = -1 = 3 = 7 = 11 = 15 = ...
```

This creates four "classes" of numbers: the only possibilities that "exist" in the modulo-4 universe. This fits, because there are only 4 possibilities a 2-bit number can assume!

Apart from division, it is just like ordinary arithmetic. 1 + 2 = 3, 2 + 2 = 4 (but we can replace 4 with 0). Consider that with a 2-bit number, 2 + 2 overflows to 0, so this is not as weird as you may initially think!

Note also that adding 1 takes you down one row, and subtracting one takes you up one row, unless you are at the edge in which case you wrap around.

(Yes, using the = sign is a bit of an abuse of notation but it is a quick way to get the point across.)

#### Unsigned Arithmetic

With unsigned arithmetic, we choose the bolded representation whenever we print or compare numbers.

```
... = -8 = -4 = 0 = 4 =  8 = 12 = ... [00b]
... = -7 = -3 = 1 = 5 =  9 = 13 = ... [01b]
... = -6 = -2 = 2 = 6 = 10 = 14 = ... [10b]
... = -5 = -1 = 3 = 7 = 11 = 15 = ... [11b]
```

As you can see this is just familiar unsigned arithmetic! \$2+2\$ will overflow (wrap around) to 0. \$0-1\$ will overflow to 3.

#### Two's complement arithmetic

With two's complement arithmetic, we choose this bolded representation whenever we print or compare numbers.

```
... = -8 = -4 = 0 = 4 =  8 = 12 = ... [00b]
... = -7 = -3 = 1 = 5 =  9 = 13 = ... [01b]
... = -6 = -2 = 2 = 6 = 10 = 14 = ... [10b]
... = -5 = -1 = 3 = 7 = 11 = 15 = ... [11b]
```

Note that we switch to the negative representation when the leftmost bit of the number is a 1, which will occur exactly halfway down.

So now, to illustrate why two's complement 11111111b = -1, note that the all-1s number has "unsigned" value \$2^n - 1\$ (see below for proof), but in two's complement notation we need to subtract \$2^n\$ because the sign bit is set, which gives \$-1\$.

Perhaps a simpler way to see it is that subtracting 1 from 0 (top row) causes a wraparound to the bottom row, and the bottom row is all-1s in binary, so that is the representation of -1.

#### Appendix

This proof is actually quite easy.

**Theorem:** an *n*-bit binary number that is all 1s has value \$v = 2^n - 1\$.

**Proof:**
By adding the place values of all bits, we have: \$v = 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^{1} + 2^0\$.

Note that:

\$2v-v = (2^{n} + 2^{n-1} + \ldots + 2^{2} + 2^1) - (2^{n-1} + 2^{n-2} + \ldots + 2^{1} + 2^0) \$.

Cancelling, we get \$v = 2^n-1\$, and we're done!

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what the negative of a number is in twos complement you "invert and add one".  so -1 means invert the value 0000...000001 giving 11111....11110 then add one giving 1111...1111.  so by definition two or more bit numbers the value of -1 is all ones.